# XSD Foreign Keys not working

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

The primary keys defined in this XML Schema with the names FKNotasAlumnos and FKNotasAsignaturas are not working, and throw this error in the validator:

```
keyref 'FKNotasAlumnos' refers to out of scope key/unique
keyref 'FKNotasAsignaturas' refers to out of scope key/unique
```

The Schema is well-formed and valid. I write it here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="bd">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="alumno" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element ref="nota" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element ref="asignatura" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="alumno">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="cod" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="apenom" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="direc" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="pobla" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="telef" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="PKAlumnos">
        <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
        <xsd:field xpath="cod"/>
    </xsd:key>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="asignatura">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="cod" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="nombre" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="PKAsignaturas">
        <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
        <xsd:field xpath="cod"/>
    </xsd:key>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="nota">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="idNota">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="alum" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="asig" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="calificacion" type="xsd:float"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="PKNotas">
        <xsd:selector xpath=".//idNota"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="alum"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="asig"/>
    </xsd:key>
    <xsd:keyref name="FKNotasAlumnos" refer="PKAlumnos">
        <xsd:selector xpath="bd/alumno/cod"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:keyref>
    <xsd:keyref name="FKNotasAsignaturas" refer="PKAsignaturas">
        <xsd:selector xpath="bd/asignatura/cod"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:keyref>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

And the "supposedly" valid XML I test the schema against is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///d:/DAW/Lenguajes%20de%20Marcas/Tarea%206/tarea6.xsd">

<alumno>
    <cod>n12344345</cod>
    <apenom>Alcalde García, Luis</apenom>
    <direc>Las Manos, 24</direc>
    <pobla>Lamadrid</pobla>
    <telef>942756645</telef>
</alumno>
<alumno>
    <cod>n43483437</cod>
    <apenom>González Pérez, Olga</apenom>
    <direc>Miraflor 28 - 3A</direc>
    <pobla>Torres</pobla>
    <telef>942564355</telef>
</alumno>
<alumno>
    <cod>n88234942</cod>
    <apenom>Fernández Díaz, María</apenom>
    <direc>Luisa Fernanda 53</direc>
    <pobla>Miera</pobla>
    <telef>942346945</telef>
</alumno>


<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n12344345</alum>
        <asig>a1</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>4</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n43483437</alum>
        <asig>a1</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>5</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n88234942</alum>
        <asig>a1</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>8</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n12344345</alum>
        <asig>a2</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>10</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n43483437</alum>
        <asig>a2</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>7</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n88234942</alum>
        <asig>a2</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>6</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n12344345</alum>
        <asig>a3</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>3</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n88234942</alum>
        <asig>a3</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>6</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n12344345</alum>
        <asig>a4</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>8</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n43483437</alum>
        <asig>a4</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>4</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n12344345</alum>
        <asig>a5</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>6</calificacion>
</nota>
<nota>
    <idNota>
        <alum>n12344345</alum>
        <asig>a6</asig>
    </idNota>
    <calificacion>9</calificacion>
</nota>


<asignatura>
    <cod>a1</cod>
    <nombre>FH</nombre>
</asignatura>
<asignatura>
    <cod>a2</cod>
    <nombre>FOL</nombre>
</asignatura>
<asignatura>
    <cod>a3</cod>
    <nombre>ISO</nombre>
</asignatura>
<asignatura>
    <cod>a4</cod>
    <nombre>LMSGI</nombre>
</asignatura>
<asignatura>
    <cod>a5</cod>
    <nombre>PAR</nombre>
</asignatura>
<asignatura>
    <cod>a6</cod>
    <nombre>GBD</nombre>
</asignatura>
</bd>
```

NOTE: The root elements are not shown, the editor takes them out.

do you have any clue on what may be failing! this is driving me nuts!

Thankyou!

Comment: I tried to create a schema with my answer below, but even after that I was getting some issues with it.  Is it possible to please have the full schema with root node and also a sample file with that root node.

Comment: I've fixed your posting; you have to indent ALL the text with four whitespaces... all your other code was indented, which is why you saw the rest, but not the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to visualize the scope of the keys... an XSD constraint is scoped to the containing element; to @Dijkgraaf's point, `PKAlumnos` is not visible outside the `alumno` element, which means it is not visible to a reference defined under `nota`; for the similar reason, `PKAsignaturas` is also not visible...

[image]

Below is your fixed XSD:

[image]

Salient points:

- Moved all the primary keys at the appropriate level. The problem with the selector... the XSD spec "roots" the XPath at the containing level... which means `.` selects the current node, which is exactly one. In a node set with exactly one node, you cannot violate a primary key...
- Fixed the `PKNotas`... wrong selector... `.//idNota` will always return exactly one node, since according to the XSD, there's exactly one idNota child; as above, with one node, you cannot break a unique constraint...

From there... this intentionally broken XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bd>

    <alumno>
        <cod>n12344345</cod>
        <apenom>Alcalde García, Luis</apenom>
        <direc>Las Manos, 24</direc>
        <pobla>Lamadrid</pobla>
        <telef>942756645</telef>
    </alumno>
    <alumno>
        <cod>n12344345</cod>
        <apenom>González Pérez, Olga</apenom>
        <direc>Miraflor 28 - 3A</direc>
        <pobla>Torres</pobla>
        <telef>942564355</telef>
    </alumno>
    <alumno>
        <cod>n88234942</cod>
        <apenom>Fernández Díaz, María</apenom>
        <direc>Luisa Fernanda 53</direc>
        <pobla>Miera</pobla>
        <telef>942346945</telef>
    </alumno>


    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n12344345-</alum>
            <asig>a1</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>4</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n43483437</alum>
            <asig>a1-</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>5</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n88234942</alum>
            <asig>a1</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>8</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n88234942</alum>
            <asig>a2</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>10</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n43483437</alum>
            <asig>a2</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>7</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n88234942</alum>
            <asig>a2</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>6</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n12344345</alum>
            <asig>a3</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>3</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n88234942</alum>
            <asig>a3</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>6</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n12344345</alum>
            <asig>a4</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>8</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n43483437</alum>
            <asig>a4</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>4</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n12344345</alum>
            <asig>a5</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>6</calificacion>
    </nota>
    <nota>
        <idNota>
            <alum>n12344345</alum>
            <asig>a6</asig>
        </idNota>
        <calificacion>9</calificacion>
    </nota>


    <asignatura>
        <cod>a1</cod>
        <nombre>FH</nombre>
    </asignatura>
    <asignatura>
        <cod>a2</cod>
        <nombre>FOL</nombre>
    </asignatura>
    <asignatura>
        <cod>a3</cod>
        <nombre>ISO</nombre>
    </asignatura>
    <asignatura>
        <cod>a4</cod>
        <nombre>LMSGI</nombre>
    </asignatura>
    <asignatura>
        <cod>a5</cod>
        <nombre>PAR</nombre>
    </asignatura>
    <asignatura>
        <cod>a1</cod>
        <nombre>FH</nombre>
    </asignatura>
</bd>
```

Would give your these error messages:

> Error occurred while loading [], line 17 position 4 There is a
>   duplicate key sequence 'n12344345' for the 'PKAlumnos' key or unique
>   identity constraint.
>
> Error occurred while loading [], line 66 position
>   5 There is a duplicate key sequence 'n88234942 a2' for the 'PKNotas'
>   key or unique identity constraint.
>
> Error occurred while loading [],
>   line 136 position 4 There is a duplicate key sequence 'a1' for the
>   'PKAsignaturas' key or unique identity constraint.
>
> Error occurred
>   while loading [], line 137 position 3 The key sequence 'n43483437' in
>   'PKAlumnos' Keyref fails to refer to some key.
>
> Error occurred while
>   loading [], line 137 position 3 The key sequence 'n12344345-' in
>   'PKAlumnos' Keyref fails to refer to some key.
>
> Error occurred while
>   loading [], line 137 position 3 The key sequence 'a1-' in
>   'PKAsignaturas' Keyref fails to refer to some key.
>
> Error occurred
>   while loading [], line 137 position 3 The key sequence 'a6' in
>   'PKAsignaturas' Keyref fails to refer to some key.

And the XSD (fixed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="bd">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="alumno" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element ref="nota" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element ref="asignatura" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:key name="PKAlumnos">
            <xsd:selector xpath="alumno"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="cod"/>
        </xsd:key>
        <xsd:key name="PKAsignaturas">
            <xsd:selector xpath="asignatura"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="cod"/>
        </xsd:key>
        <xsd:key name="PKNotas">
            <xsd:selector xpath="nota/idNota"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="alum"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="asig"/>
        </xsd:key>

    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="alumno">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="cod" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="apenom" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="direc" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="pobla" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="telef" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="asignatura">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="cod" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="nombre" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="nota">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="idNota">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="alum" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="asig" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="calificacion" type="xsd:float"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:keyref name="FKNotasAlumnos" refer="PKAlumnos">
            <xsd:selector xpath="idNota"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="alum"/>
        </xsd:keyref>
        <xsd:keyref name="FKNotasAsignaturas" refer="PKAsignaturas">
            <xsd:selector xpath="idNota"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="asig"/>
        </xsd:keyref>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

With its equivalent data set (relational) view (unfortunately, the XSD constraints are not reversible):

[image]

And one more thing... try to avoid using `float` in this type (domain) of XSDs... it has to do with precision... use xsd:decimal instead.

Comment: I got it! Thankyou very much, this answer is so helpful! I finally solved the issue with scopes pretty much the same way you did here. It  was my first schema. Thankyou also for the tip on the use of float and decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The KeyRef need to be in the same scope as the Keys they are referring.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:element name="bd">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="alumno" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="nota" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="asignatura" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="alumno">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="cod" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="apenom" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="direc" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="pobla" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="telef" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="PKAlumnos">
      <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
      <xsd:field xpath="cod"/>
    </xsd:key>
    <xsd:keyref name="FKNotasAlumnos" refer="PKAlumnos">
      <xsd:selector xpath="bd/alumno/cod"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:keyref>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="asignatura">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="cod" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="nombre" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="PKAsignaturas">
      <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
      <xsd:field xpath="cod"/>
    </xsd:key>
    <xsd:keyref name="FKNotasAsignaturas" refer="PKAsignaturas">
      <xsd:selector xpath="bd/asignatura/cod"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:keyref>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="nota">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="idNota">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="alum" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="asig" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="calificacion" type="xsd:float"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="PKNotas">
      <xsd:selector xpath=".//idNota"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="alum"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="asig"/>
    </xsd:key>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: There is still an issue with this schema however.  If I try and add a namespace to it I get.  This operation could not be completed: 
1. The 'PKAlumnos' identity constraint is not declared. 
2. The 'PKAsignaturas' identity constraint is not declared.